# Caching file request when the files are sent by PHP

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-5

I am trying to send some images to the browser using Laraval's `download()` method. I want the files be cached in browser. I tried the following without success. What it the correct way to do that?

```
$etag = md5_file($file->path);
$headers = ["cache-control" => "max-age=2592000", 'etag' => $etag];
return response()->download($path, $fileName, $headers, 'inline');
```